# Newtonsoft json exception

Tags: json, vb.net, parsing, exception

I am currently making a program that parses the Urban Dictionary API but I cannot get it to return the selected definition.

This is my current code fore retrieving and parsing the data:

```
Dim sourceString As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://api.urbandictionary.com/v0/define?term=" & strRet)

            rtxtDefinition.Text = sourceString

            Dim jResults As JArray = JArray.Parse(sourceString)
            Dim results As List(Of JToken) = jResults.Children().ToList()

            For Each item As JProperty In results
                item.CreateReader()
                MsgBox(item.Value("definition"))
            Next
```

note that strRet is the users input 
this is an example of the urban dictionary API structure: http://pastebin.com/11Z5uVRN

The current code does not have support to find the (n)th definition only because I first need to get it to return a definition.

So obviously I am doing something wrong because of the error: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException but I am not sure.

Any help would be amazing. Thanks!

EDIT: 
[image: Exception]

Comment: can you add the exception details (message, stack etc...)

Comment: It would be helpful to have the part that gets copied to the clipboard. It will tell us more about what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root of json string you're dealing with is not an array but single object. Therefore, you can parse it to `JObject` instead of `JArray`, for example :

```
Dim jobj As JObject = JObject.Parse(sourceString);
Dim arr As JArray = jobj("list");
For Each(var item in arr.Children(Of JObject)())
    MsgBox(item("definition").ToString());
Next
```

Comment: I got it to work thanks! Now I just have to figure out how to just have it pick the 1st or 2nd and so on because it is looking through like 20000 definitions...